# How to map many-to-many relation in Hibernate with a extra columns

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I would like to map a *many-to-many* relation in **Hibernate** using **XML** mapping .
I have two classes, `Voiture` and `Cient`. I want to create a link table `Reservation` witch will contain the composite key `(idClient,idVoiture)` and 3 extra columns `(dateReservation,duree,prix)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map it as composite element with a many-to-one:

```
<list ... table="LinkTable">
  ...
  <key>
    <column name="idClient" />
  </key>
  <composite-element class="MyLinkType">
    <property name="DateReservation" />
    <property name="Duree" />
    <property name="Prix" />
    <many-to-one name="Voiture" column="idVoiture" class="Voiture" />
  </composite-element>
</list>
```

Carefully consider how to make it bidirectional. The composite element is mapping properties that belong to the owner of the list.

Alternatively, make the link table an entity of its own.

Answer (score 0):

I did this, is it true ?:

Client.java:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Client implements Serializable
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
private Long idClient;
private String nom;
private String prenom;
private String cin;
private String adresse;
private String login;
private String pass;
private String numTel;
private Set<Voiture> voitures=new HashSet<Voiture>();
}
```

Client.hbm.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapp`ing PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="dao.Client" table="CLIENTS" >
<id name="idClient" column="ID_CLIENT">
<generator class="native"></generator>
</id>
<property name="nom" column="NOM"></property>
<property name="prenom" column="PRENOM"></property>
<property name="cin" column="CIN"></property>
<property name="adresse" column="ADRESSE"></property>
<property name="login" column="LOGIN"></property>
<property name="pass" column="PASS"></property>
<property name="numTel" column="NUM_TEL"></property>
    <set name="voitures" 
        lazy="true"
        cascade="all-delete-orphan">
       <key column="ID_VOITURE" />
       <one-to-many class="voiture"/>
    </set>
    </class>
```

Voiture.java:

```
 @ManagedBean
 @ViewScoped
 public class Voiture implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private Long idVoiture;
 private String marque;
 private String moteur;
 private String type;
 private Long annee;
 private Long places;
 private String boite;
 private String climatisation;
 private Double prix;
 private String dispo;
 private String image;
 private Set<Client> clients=new HashSet<Client>();
 }
```

Voiture.hbm.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
 <hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="dao.Voiture" table="VOITURES">
 <id name="idVoiture" column="ID_VOITURE">
 <generator class="native"></generator>
 </id>
 <property name="marque" column="MARQUE"></property> 
 <property name="type" column="TYPE"></property>
 <property name="prix" column="PRIX"></property>
 <property name="dispo" column="DISPO"></property> 
 <property name="climatisation" column="CLIMATISATION"></property>
 <property name="boite" column="BOITE"></property>   
 <property name="annee" column="ANNEE"></property>
 <property name="image" column="IMAGE"></property>
 <property name="places" column="PLACES"></property>
 <property name="moteur" column="MOTEUR"></property>
 <set name="clients" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
       <key column="ID_VOITURE" />
       <one-to-many class="client"/>
 </set>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Reservation.java:

```
 @ManagedBean
 @ViewScoped
 public class Reservation implements Serializable 
 {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private Long idClient;
 private Long idVoiture;
 private Date dateReservation;
 private Long duree;
 private double prix_total;
 }
```

Reseravation.hbm.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
 <hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="dao.Reservation" table="RESERVATIONS">
 <composite-id>    
    <key-many-to-one name="idClient" column="ID_CLIENT" class="CLIENT"/>
    <key-many-to-one name="idVoiture" column="ID_VOITURE" class="VOITURE"/>
 </composite-id>
 <property name="dateReservation" column="DATE_RESERVATION"/>
 <property name="duree"  column="DUREE"  />
 <property name="prix_total"  column="PRIX_TOTAL" />
 </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```